# Xcode - Label won't autoshrink when the number is decimal

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am making an application that calculates some numbers, some of the answers have no decimal and some have. So I made an if-else, to format the numbers using `NSNumberFormatter` depending if they have decimals or not.

When it doesn't, everything works fine, the number is correctly formatted and the label autoshrinks correctly. However, when the number has decimals, it won't autoshrink. What it will do is deleting the last decimals if all the number won't enter the label, until there are no decimals. Then it will work fine

For example, if I have "123,456,789.123456789", the label won't be big enough to show all of that and it will instead show "123,456,789.1234". If I change the parameters so the answer will be 10x that, the answer will be "1,234,567,891.234". Now until I get to "1,234,567,891,234", it won't autoshrink to let me see the numbers. However, when the number has no decimals, it will autoshrink and I will see all the numbers.

Here's the code that works (when there is no decimals):

```
NSNumber *input = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: numberDouble];  
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];  
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];  
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];  
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];  
stringWithDecimals = [formatter stringFromNumber:input];  
NSMutableString* someString = [NSMutableString stringWithString: stringWithDecimals];  
[someString appendString: @" unit"];  
stringWithDecimals = someString;  
label.text = stringWithDecimals;
```

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
NSNumber *input = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: numberDouble];  
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];  
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];  
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];  
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];  
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];  
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];  
stringWithDecimals = [formatter stringFromNumber:input];  
NSMutableString* someString = [NSMutableString stringWithString: stringWithDecimals];  
[someString appendString: @" unit"];  
stringWithDecimals = someString;  
label.text = stringWithDecimals;
```

The variable "numberDouble" is a double.

So what I am trying to do is make it work for the second case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you mean autoshrink, but you can always convert the number to a string (which you have to do in order to put it into the label, anyways) and then use NSString's instance method sizeWithFont: to get the size required for your label to display the number in its entirety.

The code would be something like this:

```
NSString *yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", yourNumber];
CGSize labelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourFont];
```

Comment: I tried a few times and I didn't get it to work. Look at the desciption of the problem, I have added the code, that could help you to understand. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: Take your final string with decimals at the end and get the sizeWithFont: from it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a `UILabel` I don't think it has any support for automatically change its bounds when the text is changed (you can test it by setting the background color and see the actual size).

But you can manually send `sizeToFit` to the label after updating the text to make it change its bounds to fit all text.

Comment: I don't want to change its bounds, I want to change the size of the font so it will fit in the label. The actual UILabel will always be the same size, however the size of the numbers, or font, will change.

Comment: Just tried, it doesn't work. As soon as a decimal is there, the font size won't adjust. The only difference when there are decimals in my if-else case is that I use setNumberStyle:NSNumberFornatterDecimalStyle in a NSNumberFormatter. That could be where the problem is...

Comment: Hmm `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` seams to work for me with both "123456789123456789" and "123,456,789.123456789", the label adjusts the font so all of text is shown. You make a screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: I added the code, take a look! There are a few things I didn't mention that you will see, I hope that will help to find the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you include the relevant label creation or modification code too? or at least how it is setup, size adjust, truncation etc.

Comment: That is the only code for the label. Everything else was done in the storyboard. I changed nothing, so the label has all the default settings (autoshrink is enabled).

Comment: Ah ok, your using interface builder. So "Minimum size" is set to 10 then? try to set it to zero as i think "autoshrink" is the same as `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` which will not adjust the font to be smaller then the minimum.

Comment: It's still not working with decimals. Like before, the size adjusts only when there is no decimals.

Comment: Do you see a "..." truncation? also make sure the label frame is partially outside the window or it's parent view. Lines is set to 1 so it could not be word line breaks somehow?

Comment: No truncation, line is set to 1. I really think the problem is that there is something missing in the code, since it works with numbers without decimal. Perharps the label doesn't recognize a NSString correctly when there are decimals?

Comment: Sounds very weird if that was the case. Try to use NSLog to make sure you actually have the correct strings.

Comment: Hmm The NSLog is the same as the label, so the label is actually showing the right thing. The problem is probably with the NSNumberFormatter, since I have used NSLog at every step, up until the last line of the NSNumberFormatter, and it was always not the real number. Any idea?